# How are secret service agents expected to respond if the POTUS attacks someone?

Tags: united-states, president, secret-service

One of the US secret service's primary duties is to provide protection to the POTUS, but what if the POTUS were to become homicidal and take an unprovoked violent action against an apparently non-violent target?

What actions would the presidential security detail be expected to take should the President, as an example, start a punching a journalist that recently asked, from the presidents perspective, an offensive and inappropriate question?

Comment: A president is not immune from the law, and the secret service would probably try holding them back.

Comment: @SleepingGod - but then the agents holding him back might be interpreted as assaulting the president, so *other* agents would step in and kick their butts......

Comment: @PoloHoleSet this is unlikely at best, remember they work as teams often training for years together. They would be well trained in communicating and reaching a concensus very quickly as to hold back a president

Comment: @SleepingGod - yes, but humorous vignettes offered entirely as jokes rarely have to be extremely likely.

Comment: There is no safe way to fistfight. If the president is physically involved in a confrontation I would be very surprised if the secret service cared who started it. Other guy(s) on the floor, president out the door.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific.  I believe this should be on topic.\

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - prior to 2000s and all the USSS scandals, I'd say "USSS hires intelligent people who'd clearly obviously interpret 'save the President from his own temper' as valid reason for (in)action' ". **You can get hurt physically, punching someone** (never mind, political self damage).

Comment: @user4012 - very true, especially since most people don't even know how to make a fist correctly, let along strike someone with it.  I LOL'd at your qualification on that.  That group has had a poor run lately.  On a more general note, I'm not sure I like Soylent's edit.  I took the question to be more along the lines if the president decided to punch out or rough up someone, would they be expected to try and stop him, less so than something authentically murderous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While we haven't had a recent example, after somebody attempted to assassinate former President Andrew Jackson, Jackson proceeded to assault the man with his cane, at which point the Secret Service pulled Jackson off of the would-be assassin before he could kill him. I imagine that if they would pull the president off a would-be assassin, they would certainly restrain him from assaulting an innocent reporter.

Comment: The Andrew Jackson incident was in 1835. The Secret Service wasn't established until 1865 and wasn't tasked with protecting the POTUS' personal safety until 1901. So the people who restrained Jackson were not Secret Service agents.

Comment: In 1842 the first presidentail security force was established for the white house but would be expanded during the civil war to protect the president everywhere.  https://www.whitehousehistory.org/secret-service-and-the-presidents

Comment: Interestingly enough [Davy Crockett](http://www.politico.com/story/2008/01/jackson-escapes-assassination-attempt-jan-30-1835-008184) was one of the men who saved the would be assassin

Comment: Cool, got proof? ;)

Comment: @Tirous According to the Smithsonian, "Navy Lieutenant Thomas Gedney and Tennessee congressman Davy Crockett had subdued Lawrence and hurried the president off to a carriage so he could be transported to the White House"